# Why don't all main menu tags display for anon user on my Drupal-7.39 ste?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In the process of migrating a Drupal 7.24 site to a new server running 7.39.  While most of it looks OK, when accessing the home page without being logged in the main menu only shows two tabs on the new site but all the tags on the old site.  However, if I log in as administrator on the new site all the tabs are displayed.   I've looked through any permissions issues I could think of and the only js errors I'm seeing is the typekit.net access delay.
Of course I've searched this and Drupal's site almost until I can't read anymore so if anyone has any suggestions or who might have seen this issue before and resolved it I would very much appreciate hearing/reading from you.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you mean server is running Drupal 7.39?! Drupal is part of you site. How did you move the site?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that menu links to unpublished items in Drupal will not show for anonymous users.  Perhaps the status of your migrated nodes changed during the transition?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I've checked all the items in the menu and all are "published" and compared to the live site they look identical. Addressing the first comment the migration method was to dump the database with mysqldump, Run sed to change all the site url referenced from www.domain to test.domain then build the new database from the resulting file.  Then the directory tree was moved to the new system then updated to the latest version (7.39 at the time) and the update procedure run.  All went well and virtually everything works as expected except for this strange main menu item.